Karate - Setting header for the subsequent calls on the same scenario is not working after updating to 1.x.x
We have been using Karate 0.9.6 so far and everything was working, and we had to update to latest version(1.4.1) and test started breaking, below is an example how the scenarios are created,

Login with credentials
Get the cookie
Make an API call to get the transaction token by setting the cookie as header. Ex


header Cookie = cookie (Header with cookie set up property)


Get the transaction token from the response
Make last API call by setting the cookie and token in the header. Ex


header Cookie = cookie
header txtToken = txtToken

But the last API call has header with new cookie from the responseCookies of the previous call instead of the cookie has been set
Note: the host url on step 3 and 5 are same only path url is different.
I believe the fix that was made here https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1526 is forced to use the previous call response cookie rathe  which was set as part of the call.
I tried setting the global headers as per this solution Authorization header not working for second request in same scenario but that did not help

I'm sorry you have to figure this out on your own based on all the release notes since 0.9.6 - I suggest you follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - and if you discover a bug in karate it can be fixed

Thank you @PeterThomas. I have created an issue https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2553

and I have just closed it. please follow the process
